# Units of FFT frequency

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

I'm having some trouble understanding `FFT` plots and measures.

[image]

According to this, this will give me the magnitude plot of `FFT`, but I want the area under from `1 to 10 Hz` for example.

Is this next formula I made right?

[image]

My doubt is, what's the relation between `Hz` and `rad/s`, `f` and `w`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you made will work if what you are after is simply "the area under the the magnitude plot from $\omega_i$ to $\omega_f$."

In many cases you can think of `Hz` as meaning "rotations per second."  In that case, it becomes more obvious that 1 rotation = 2$\pi$ radians.  Since $f$ has units of `Hz` and $\omega$ has units of radians, the conversion is simply:
$$
1 \, \text{Hz} = 2 \pi \, \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}
$$
So evaluate your integration from $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ to $\frac{10}{2\pi}$ and you should have the result you are after.

Comment: @nisplo how come I didn't think in converting the unit?? :P Thank you very much. :)